# Cosine Transformation

Tags: trigonometry

How does $$A_c\mu\cos (2\pi f_m t) \cos (2\pi f_c t)$$ become $$\mu A_c\frac{\cos(2\pi f_mt-2\pi f_ct)-\cos(2\pi f_mt+2\pi f_ct)}{2}?$$ What is the formula used?

Comment: Not very pleasant to read it...

Comment: @Surb sorry dont know to type it properly.Please refer this http://www.slideshare.net/AvinashKumar449/16analog-communication-by-kprabhakara-rao Its under amplitude modulation

Comment: Werner formulas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis#The_identities

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect; what is true is that $$A_c\mu\cos 2\pi f_m t \cos 2\pi f_c t=\mu A_c\frac{\cos(2\pi f_mt-2\pi f_ct)+\cos(2\pi f_mt+2\pi f_ct)}{2}$$
(note the plus sign on the right-hand side).
This comes from the identity $$\cos A\cos B=\frac{\cos(A-B)+\cos(A+B)}{2},$$
with $A=2\pi f_mt$ and $B=2\pi f_ct$.
To prove this identity, note that $$\cos(A+B)=\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B$$ and $$\cos(A-B)=\cos A \cos B+\sin A\sin B,$$
so the $\sin$ terms cancel out when you add them and you get $$\cos(A+B)+\cos(A-B)=2\cos A\cos B.$$